# Make Error in OSX Yosemite: no matching function for call to 'isnan(double&)

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, makefile, osx-yosemite

This issue might be too specialized to my particular problem. Please let me know, and I'll delete the question.

I'm trying to install the [MIT Language Modeling Toolkit](https://github.com/orezpraw/MIT-Language-Modeling-Toolkit). I've installed the dependencies, and `./autogen.sh` works fine. However, when I compile with `make`, I get:

```
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/include/c++/5.0.0/cassert:43:0,
                 from src/util/FastHash.h:39,
                 from src/Vocab.h:39,
                 from src/NgramLM.h:42,
                 from src/KneserNeySmoothing.cpp:37:
src/KneserNeySmoothing.cpp: In member function 'virtual void KneserNeySmoothing::Initialize(NgramLM*, size_t)':
src/KneserNeySmoothing.cpp:93:20: error: no matching function for call to 'isnan(double&)'
     assert(!isnan(Y));
                    ^
In file included from src/Types.h:41:0,
                 from src/NgramLM.h:41,
                 from src/KneserNeySmoothing.cpp:37:
src/vector/VectorOps.h:224:1: note: candidate: template<class V> const UnaryVectorClosure<OpIsNan, V> isnan(const Vector<I>&)
 isnan(const Vector<V> &x) { return UnaryVectorClosure<OpIsNan, V>(x.impl()); }
 ^
src/vector/VectorOps.h:224:1: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/include/c++/5.0.0/cassert:43:0,
                 from src/util/FastHash.h:39,
                 from src/Vocab.h:39,
                 from src/NgramLM.h:42,
                 from src/KneserNeySmoothing.cpp:37:
src/KneserNeySmoothing.cpp:93:20: note:   mismatched types 'const Vector<I>' and 'double'
     assert(!isnan(Y));
                    ^
make[1]: *** [src/KneserNeySmoothing.lo] Error 1
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Do I need to update a gcc or c++ dependency? Is this just a bug in the code?

Running OSX 10.10.3, a beta Yosemite, which could also be an issue.

**UPDATE**
I followed Daniel Frey's advice, ran `make clean`, and then `make`, and now get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy::_M_need_rehash(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
      std::_Hashtable<unsigned long, std::pair<unsigned long const, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned long const, int> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<unsigned long>, std::hash<unsigned long>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true> >::_M_insert_unique_node(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<unsigned long const, int>, false>*) in evaluate-ngram.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [evaluate-ngram] Error 1
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: Could you give your question a more useful title? (looks like a bug in the code, missing `#include <math.h>` or something like that)

Comment: Sure. Is that better?

Comment: Got it. Done. I apologize, I'm out of my element here.

Comment: Try including `<cmath>` and qualify the call with `std::isnan` - does that help?

Comment: I'm not sure. I now have a different error, updated above.

Comment: Looks like it is linking with gcc instead of g++? (or there is some mix-up with clang-libc++, but that seems less likely for now)

Comment: What should I do about that? I thought it was supposed to compile with gcc.

Comment: gcc is for C code, g++ for C++ code. What does the command line above the error look like?

Comment: `libtool: link: g++ -std=c++11 -g -O2 -o .libs/evaluate-ngram src/evaluate-ngram.o -Wl,-bind_at_load  ./.libs/libmitlm.dylib -lzmq`

Comment: Ah, I guessed wrong.